# Can I clear the status of the colored bars in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I know the bars on that show up on the left reflect the change status of my code (green is saved changes, yellow means changes were made and not saved, etc.) but is there a way to clear these bars out **without** closing and reopening Visual Studio?
I think they are helpful markers, but they begin to help less and less as I make more changes throughout a large file (or multiple files)

Comment: You can close and reopen *just that file*. That also does it.

Comment: Also, if you follow best practices when programming, there's no way you can create a large file. So maybe rethink your process?

Comment: Large to me is along the lines of (no pun intended) 750+ lines of code. It wouldn't make sense to break up these files as many of them are various preferences and settings. The properties of which *can* get complex, so that doesn't help. I'd post an example to show you, but I don't own the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Closing and reopening the file (not the whole IDE) will reset the change tracking.

Comment: The [Productivity Power Tools](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/dbcb8670-889e-4a54-a226-a48a15e4cace) add-in contains an "undo close" keyboard shortcut that makes this especially easy.